# Problem using OpenCV and Raspberry PI camera V2

Tags: python, opencv, picamera, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I had been using the following code for the past two months with no problem whatsoever, however, just yesterday I have been getting errors using the code which I will detail as follows. The code in question is used to take photos of objects using the raspberry pi camera.

I initialize the raspberry pi camera v2 using the following code -

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/dev/video0', cv2.CAP_V4L)

#set dimensions
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 2560)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1440)
```

After which I take a photo from the camera and write the image to a filename using the following lines of code -

```
ret, frame = cap.read()
cv2.imwrite(fileName , frame)
```

I have been getting the following error quite recently -

```
[ WARN:0@26.652] global /io/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (1000) tryIoctl VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): select() timeout.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/proj_trash_can/main.py", line 55, in <module>
    clickPicture(cam_capture, filename)
  File "/home/pi/Documents/proj_trash_can/cam.py", line 22, in clickPicture
    cv2.imwrite(fileName , frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) /io/opencv/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:801: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_img.empty() in function 'imwrite'
```

Could someone kindly help me find the solution to my problem ? I would greatly appreciate it. I am able to share any more details as per your requests.